# FlatButton onPressed Not Working In Positioned Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**Whenever I used FlatButton onPressed Method Is Not Working In Positioned Widget.**

I am designing one screen in that buttons are always in the bottom of the screen and that button click we can move to other screens,but here it is not working, can anyone check and help me out.thaks in advance

```
           child: Stack(
               // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
               children: <Widget>[
                     Positioned(
                         left: 0,
                         bottom: 0,
                           // alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                           child: Row(
                             mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                             children: <Widget>[
                               SizedBox(height: 115),
                               ButtonTheme(
                                 minWidth:
                                     MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                                 height: 60.0,
                                 child: FlatButton.icon(
                                   icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.fileInvoice),
                                   color: Colors.white,
                                   onPressed: () {
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen());
                                   },
                                   label: Text(
                                     "My Orders",
                                     textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                     style: TextStyle(
                                       // decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                       fontSize: 25,
                                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                       color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                     ),
                                   ),
                                 ),
                               ),
                               SizedBox(height: 115),
                               ButtonTheme(
                                 minWidth:
                                     MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                                 height: 60.0,
                                 child: FlatButton.icon(
                                   icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.dollarSign),
                                   color: Colors.white60,
                                   onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                                       context, '/home');
                                   },
                                   label: Text(
                                     "Bean Balnace",
                                     textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                     style: TextStyle(
                                       // decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                       fontSize: 20,
                                       color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                     ),
                                   ),
                                 ),
                               ),
                             ],
                           )),
```

Comment: Any errors you are getting?

Comment: nope, just onPressed is not working...

Comment: Are both the buttons not working?

Comment: yes, both of not working

Comment: I can see any reason as to why this shouldn't work, as long as MainScreen() exists and that you have setup the /home routing then it should work. Are you sure there isn't any errors within the debug console?

Comment: @Max Macfarlane  yes, there are no errors in debug consile..

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen());
```

to this:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your case and am able to navigate to new screen after tapping on both buttons. Here's the full code I tried:

declared `/home` route as:

```
return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/home': (context) => NextScreen()
      },
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
```

Then, it's pretty much the code you shared apart from minor changes in `My Orders` `onPressed()` event:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            // alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 115),
                ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth:
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                  height: 60.0,
                  child: FlatButton.icon(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.forward),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextScreen()));
                    },
                    label: Text(
                      "My Orders",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        // decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 115),
                ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth:
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                  height: 60.0,
                  child: FlatButton.icon(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.business),
                    color: Colors.white60,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                          context, '/home');
                    },
                    label: Text(
                      "Bean Balnace",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        // decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
        ]
      )
      )
    );
```

`NextScreen` class:

```
class NextScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your widget as last widget of Stack widget children.